# Pythonic way to import multiple dictionaries from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a text file,

```
question_one = {question:"what is 2+2", answer: "4", fake1: "5"}
question_two = {question:"what is the meaning of life?", answer:"pizza", fake:"42"}
```

How can I then import these dictionaries so that I could use them like this,

```
print(question_one["question"])
print(question_two["question"])
```

So the out come would be

```
what is 2+2
what is the meaning of life?
```

I would like this so that I can add questions to a text file from within the program and then save them should I add more, If this is possible another way please let me know!

Comment: You could store a json object to a file: importing those is much easier since you can then just iterate over the questions.

Comment: Have you tried to do anything at all?

Comment: Ah i havent heard of how to do that with json objects, I'll have a look now,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to store your questions into a JSON file, like [@Thom Wiggers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248065/) is suggesting.

Here's an example:

```json
[
    {
        "question": "what is 2+2", 
        "answer": "4", 
        "fake1": "5"
    },
    {
        "question": "what is the meaning of life?", 
        "answer": "pizza", 
        "fake1": "42"
    }
]
```

```py
import json

with open('questions.json') as f:
    questions = json.load(f)
    for question in questions:
        print(question['question'])
```

You can read more about the JSON module in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html).

Comment: This looks like the way, Can I ask how would I change that with statement to only print the question I would like, as the current one prints all the questions out, Thank you

Comment: @jack `questions` is a [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) and it can be indexed like any sequence: for example `questions[0]` returns the first question. Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes I found a way to do it, please can you have a look and see if it pythonically * correct, as in I could improve something, https://gist.github.com/jackdh/8940057

Answer (score 1):

If you *only* want to serialize data, you want to use [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [`json`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). `exec` will execute *all* Python code, and can be a serious security problem.
`pickle` is faster, and is specificity tailored to Python, while `json` can be read & written work by just about any programming language, and is still fairly human-readable & human-editable.

Now, to answer the question as you asked it (you probably don't want to do this):

You can use [`exec()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec)

> This function supports dynamic execution of Python code. object must
>   be either a string or a code object. If it is a string, the string is
>   parsed as a suite of Python statements which is then executed (unless
>   a syntax error occurs).

ie.

`exec(open('data.txt', 'r').read())`

Another way to do is would be to (ab)use `import`, assuming your file is named `data.py`:

```
import data

data.question_one['question']
```

This is obviously not what `import` was intended for... I've 'used' import like this in the past, and regretted it (there are a number of caveats, I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to think about what they might be).

**Warning** Both are [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval#Security_risks)-like statements, and should be used with care, **any** Python code in `data.txt` will be executed, which may be potentially dangerous. Be *very* sure you trust the source of whatever you pass to `exec()`, and *don't* use if you only want to serialize data (instead of running Python code as such).

Comment: I think it's irresponsible to suggest `exec` when there are many other alternatives available, especially `json`. Even `csv` would work.

Comment: what's the caveats of the second way? I'm making my config files python code and load them just as you say...

Comment: @2rs2ts Thanks for your feedback. I think it would depend on what *exactly* the OP is trying to do; you can do `if`s and whatnot in `exec()`. I've made (valid) use of `exec()`... I included the obligatory warning, but I'll word it a bit stronger.